# Share code between asmx and wcf

Tags: c#, wcf, architecture, asmx

I've got wcf service. Also some our clients use delphi7 to consume our sevices. Delphi7 couldn't conusme wcf (even basicHttpBinding) so I have to create asmx analogue of my wcf web service. Now I'm searching better way build wcf and asmx service on the same code base. What is the preferable way to build, maintain two services with ths same code (the same methods,logic)

Thanks Andrew

Comment: WCF with BasicHttpBinding is equivalent to asmx. What problems do you encounter? Are you using the correct url to get to the wsdl?

Comment: I know. It's Delphi7 issue. Wsdl's are different

Comment: Delphi7 should have no problem with a WCF service using `basicHttpBinding`. It's hard to imagine what kind of WSDL difference could break Delphi or any other program. You should ask a specific question about your specific service, and you'll likely find out what's wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a dynamic link library (*.dll) to house shared code, reference and utilise from both projects.

This way you have two services for appropriate platforms which just call methods exposed by the shared code-base, which, when edited in one place and further deployed, is applicable all callers.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you could create a BusinessManager which encapsulates all the logic then from wcf or asmx you simply create an instance of it and call the proper method passing the actual parameters received from your caller.

I use the word BusinessManager to define the class has something to do with your own business logic, but it's simply a class, either static or not, I usually prefer to do not make such classes static.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily add a plain old ASMX webservice to your existing WCF Service if it's already hosted in an ASP.NET Web Application/Site.

Right-click your project -> Add -> New Item
Select Web -> scroll to bottom -> Web Service.

Then have your web service call your WCF methods.

Comment: I think it's would be slow. I don't need chain of services.

Comment: That's not what I meant, just instantiate the xxService class and call methods immediately without going through the "calling a service" ordeal.

Answer (score 0):

Delphi 7 supports calling out to COM (ActiveX) objects, does it not?

Why not build a COMVisible .NET client for your WCF service, and consume that in Delphi via a COM interface.

That way you don't have to maintain both an ASMX and a WCF service.